# How to define a function and assign values to variables in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a clicker game and when you buy an autoClickerIt doubles in price. This is so players can't spam buy. However, it just gets too insane when you get into the higher prices, so I want the price to increase by one quarter of itself. Logically, if the variable for the price is called A, we should be able to do something like...

```
<button onClick="buyAutoClicker">
<script>
  function buyAutoClicker();
    A + (A * 0.25)
</script>`
```

However this doesn't work.

Comment: You do realize that the result of `A + (A * 0.25)` is not being assigned to anything, right?

Comment: You could do `A *= 1.25`. But your code is not valid javascript.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

So one problem is probably in how you're defining your function. Function declarations have the following syntax

```
function myStringConcater(arg1, arg2) {
    console.log(arg1 + arg2);
}
// invoke it like so...
myStringConcater('h', 'i');
```

You can find more details on that here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function

For the example you showed above you could do

```
function buyAutoClicker() {
    A = A + (A * 0.25)
}
```